# How to get floated divs align to the top?

Tags: css, html

The code below can be viewed in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VgG55/10/

I have the following markup where the divs are placed in the following order:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wide">Prio 1</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 2</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 3</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 4</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 5</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 6</div>
    <div class="wide">Prio 7
        <br/>The divs can vary in height.
        <br/>So, the height must be able to change.</div>
    <div class="wide">Prio 8</div>
    <div class="wide">Prio 9</div>
    <div class="wide">Prio 10</div>
    <div class="narrow">Prio 11</div>
    <div class="wide">Prio 12</div>
</div>
```

I wish to place the "wide" divs to the left and the "narrow" divs to the right. The height of the divs may vary.

The following CSS is used as a start (but may be changed):

```
.wide {
    background: gray;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.narrow {
    background: green;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

The desired result result is not achieved since there are large empty spaces between the divs vertically (both for the "wide" and "narrow" side).

How can I align the divs vertically (without space)? The order of the "prio" divs must stay intact in the document but I am allowed to change the CSS and insert extra divs (wrappers etc).

As a final note, a no-JS solution is required.

Comment: Can you sort the divs?

Comment: The demo seems to work for me (without "vertical spaces" if I understand it well).

Comment: The white space at the last div seems to be the issue.

Comment: are these divs dynamic or are they static? When I say static I mean, are the divs being created by php or some sort of jquery/javascript'

Comment: Hm, the markup can unfortunately not be changed. I have updated with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VgG55/4/

In chrome/firefox on mac there is a vertical space both on the left and on the right (on the left between div 1 and 6, on the right between 5 an 10)

Comment: @Cam - the divs are static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using float, but you can try to use a javascript masonry plugin like:

http://masonry.desandro.com/ or http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that @parchambault but this is unfortunately a no-js solution.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to achieve my goal - unfortunately I can't use this solution (since I can't use JS) but it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VgG55/7/

Here is alternative way to approach the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="wide">
        <div>Prio 1</div>
        <div>Prio 4</div>
        <div>Prio 5</div>
        <div>Prio 6</div>
        <div>Prio 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="narrow">
        <div>Prio 2</div>
        <div>Prio 3</div>
        <div>Prio 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}

.wide {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.narrow {
    background: green;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the order of the divs. I am allowed to insert wrappers and extra divs but the prio order must stay intact in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you can resort the divs you could do something like this instead.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="wide">Prio 1</div>
   <div class="wide">Prio 2</div>
   <div class="wide">Prio 3</div>
   <div class="wide">Prio 4</div>
   <div class="wide">Prio 5</div>
   <div class="narrow">Prio 6</div>
   <div class="narrow">Prio 7</div>
   <div class="narrow">Prio 8</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.wide {
    background: gray;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.narrow {
    background: green;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible - the order of the divs and the classes must remain. But I can add extra divs around the existing divs if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

### For equal-sized boxes

use `inline-block`, but *not* `float`, for the `wide` class

```
.wide {
  background: gray;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9U2X/)

---

### For variable-sized boxes

The above method doesn't work well with boxes of different heights, as the floated elements try to maintain the height of the original row, or something.

I managed to hack together something ugly but functional using `flex-box`:

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  /* adjust for the relative re-positioning
     from the hack, below */
  margin-bottom:-150px; 
}
.wide {
  order:0; /* re-order the wide elements to the "start", i.e. top */
  width:79%; /* this could be done with flex:xxx */
}
.narrow {
  order:1; /* re-order the narrows to the "end" */
  align-self:flex-end; /* moves the narrows to the right */
  width:20%; /* again this could be flex:xxx */
  /* the awful hack: */
  position:relative;
  top:-150px; /* magic number: trial and error required */
}
```

Flexbox should be able to do a 2-column stack. Unfortunately it's [not yet supported in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=939901) (looks like it's due in v28, so mid-March maybe). Also, I couldn't get it to work in a fiddle in Chrome.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9U2X/2/)

Comment: That sort of solves the problem! On Firefox it works out well but on Chrome there is a "gap" over the first "narrow" div.

Comment: Dammit, chrome. If you can remove all whitespace around the children of `.wrapper` the problem goes away.

Comment: Alternatively, if you allow a gap (e.g. size the `wide`s as 79% rather than 80%), it works well.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, even if I lower the gap to 79% it does not work. The divs can be of various height as in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9U2X/1/

Comment: @wassgren see updated answer. Ugly hack, but it seems to work. Obviously, you'll have to figure out the appropriate offset to use (rather than -150px).