# Markup and CSS for responsive layout, floated divs aligned to top

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a web page that contains a series of components (boxes). Each component *can vary in height* since the content is dynamic. Furthermore, the components should be fluid (i.e. the width may vary to a certain extent).

The problem is that I want "different ordering" when viewing the web page for desktop and smartphone.

```
Smartphone    Desktop
┌───┐         ┌─────┬───┐
│ A │         │  A  │ B │
│   │         │     ├───┤
├───┤         ├─────┤ C │
│ B │         │  D  ├───┤
├───┤         ├─────┤ E │
│ C │         │  F  │   │
├───┤         ├─────┤   │
│ D │         │  G  ├───┘
├───┤         └─────┘
│ E │        
│   │        
│   │        
├───┤        
│ F │        
├───┤        
│ G │        
└───┘
```

Basically, I want to "float" some components to the right and some to the left when the user views the desktop version. And I want another "order" for the mobile version.

I have tried simple "float: right" and "float: left" combined with media queries for the two resolutions but that leads to vertical gaps in the layout as per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VgG55/10/ that was used in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006346/how-to-get-floated-divs-align-to-the-top).

In order to achieve this, what kind of markup (order of divs, wrappers etc) should be used and what the CSS look like for a "wide" and "narrow" version?

Note, a JS solution such as http://masonry.desandro.com/ can not be used. This should be pure HTML/CSS (if possible). Furthermore, the website should work for IE9+ and modern versions of Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could come up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/VgG55/11/

Note that I had to change the ordering of the divs though and enclose in spans:

```
<span class="wide">
```

Answer (score -1):

i solved problems like this using separate `<div>` for each column

```
<div class="column col1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="column col2">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

for desktop you `.column { float: left}` them

for mobile . they come on after another